# Im trying to save custom data to cloud firestore in swiftUI, Im trying to construct the data i get from snapshot listener

Tags: swift, swiftui, codable

The call `document.data(as: )` requires `Decodable` protocol, it saves the data just fine as the call to `addDocument(from:)` requires encodable object so I pass my custom class object, yet I don't know why the other way around requires the protocol.
How do I pass the protocol?

Here is my custom class definition :

```
class PersonalInfo: Codable, ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var age: Int
    @Published var Sex: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey{
        case name, age, Sex
    }
    init(name: String, age:Int, Sex:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.Sex = Sex
    }
    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        age = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .age)
        Sex = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .Sex)
    }
    public func encode( to encoder: Encoder) throws{
        var container = try encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(age, forKey: .age)
        try container.encode(Sex, forKey: .Sex)
    }     
}
```

Here is the function I am trying to construct the data after getting  set of data:

```
mutating func loadData(){
        let listener = query?.addSnapshotListener{ (snapShot, error ) in
            guard let snapshot = snapShot else {
                print("Error listening")
                return
            }
            let userCollection = try? snapshot.documents.map{ document -> PersonalInfo in
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let user = try document.data(as: PersonalInfo(from: decoder)){
                    return user
                }
                else{
                    fatalError("unable to initialize type")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question starts with *Im trying to save custom data to cloud firestore* but there's nothing in the question that attempts to* save custom data*. The second part is *construct the data i get from snapshot listener*, and while that code exists, the code doesn't actually do anything as the `userCollection` goes out of scope when the function ends. Can you clarify what's being asked and include the associated code along with describing what the code is not doing and what the expected outcome is?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a class for your data **structure**. A Class: **ObservableObject** accepts, processes, and passes (published) needed data(values) to your View according to your data **structure**...
A good news: Firebase supports the Swift Codable Protocol – check this [link](https://youtu.be/3-yQeAf3bLE)